# Kivymd APK App (created with Buildozer) closes after opening up

Tags: python, keras, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I have created an APK file from Python Kivy & KivyMD, using Buildozer. When I open the app after installing it, it shows the splash image and then closes.
I have checked and found that their seems no issue in the main.py, as I have correctly listed Kivy & KivyMD in the requirements in the Buildozer.spec file. (kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1)

This is my code..

**main.py**

```
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
import helper
import model

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(helper.navigation_helper)
        return self.screen

    def show_data(self): #(self,obj):
        self.abc = model.chat(self.screen.ids.user_name.text)
        close_button = MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialog)
        self.dialog = MDDialog(title='First-aid Suggested..', text=self.abc, size_hint=(0.7, 1), buttons=[close_button])
        self.dialog.open()
    
    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

DemoApp().run()
```

**model.py**

```
import nltk
# nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
import numpy
import random
import json
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)           # ['What', 'to', 'do', 'if', 'Cuts', '?']
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)                          # input data (x)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])                 # corresponding output data (y)

    if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])                 # all possible output data

words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels)


training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]              # [1,2,3] [0,0,0]

for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []

    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]               # doc = ['What', 'to', 'do', 'if', 'Cuts', '?']   &    wrds = ['What', 'to', 'do', 'if', 'Cut', '?']

    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("First_Aid_model.h5")

def bag_of_words(s,words):
  bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]
  s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
  s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]
  for se in s_words:
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
      if w == se:
        bag[i] = 1
  return bag


def chat(inp):
    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp,words)])
    result = results[0]
    results_index = numpy.argmax(result)
    tag = labels[results_index]
    if result[results_index] > 0.5:
      for tg in data["intents"]:
        if tg['tag'] == tag:
          responses = tg['responses']
      res = random.choice(responses).split('. ')
      res = [res[_]+'.' for _ in range(len(res)) if  not res[_].endswith('.')]
      res = ('\n').join(res)
      return(res + "\n")
    else:
      return("I didnt get that, try again")
```

**helper.py**

```
navigation_helper = """
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                    Widget:
                    MDTextField:
                        id: user_name
                        hint_text: "Enter username"
                        helper_text: "or click on forgot username"
                        helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                        icon_right: "redhat"
                        icon_right_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        size_hint_x:None
                        width:300
                        
                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: "Show"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        on_release: app.show_data()
                    
                    Widget:
                    
                    
                    
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: "8dp"
                spacing: "8dp"
                Image:
                    id: avatar
                    size_hint: (1,1)
                    source: "Capture.PNG"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "First-aid Bot"
                    font_style: "Subtitle1"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                MDLabel:
                    text: "gtanish2020@gmail.com"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_style: "Caption"
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                ScrollView:
                        
                    MDList:
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Profile"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "face-profile"
                                    
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Upload"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "upload"
                                    
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Logout"
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "logout"
                            
"""
```

**buildozer.spec**

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Bot

# (str) Package name
package.name = bot

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.bot

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

According to me, the issue is coming as in the model.py file, I have imported modules like Keras, NLTK etc..and I am not mentioning them in requirements.
If this is the issue, then please give the complete statement which I should write in the requirements, according to my model.py & others
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some other plugins just add them like this:

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1,pluginname==version
```

Comment: I don't know what versions and all to use for json. random etc. So Seeing my model.py & others, can you only tell how can I add them pls ? I would be very thankful

Comment: Go to File > Settings > Project: "yourproject name" > Python Interpreter

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you won't be able to run your app under Android.

Your requirements should include:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,keras,tensorflow,nltk,numpy,kivymd,regex
```

To include your additional files:

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,h5,json,PNG
```

But tensorflow used by keras got an issue on Android:

```
  File ".../keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File ".../keras/models/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File ".../keras/engine/functional.py", line 24, in <module>
  File ".../tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
  File ".../tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File ".../tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 26, in <module>
  File ".../tensorflow/python/platform/self_check.py", line 63, in preload_check
ImportError: dlopen failed: undefined symbol: eglGetPlatformDisplayEXT
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common causes and solutions.
If you need help, create an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and include the entire stack trace above this error message.
```

Line 63 of self_check.py is:

```
# Load a library that performs CPU feature guard checking.  Doing this here
# as a preload check makes it more likely that we detect any CPU feature
# incompatibilities before we trigger them (which would typically result in
# SIGILL).
from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_cpu_feature_guard    # <<< this is line 63
_pywrap_cpu_feature_guard.InfoAboutUnusedCPUFeatures()
```

`_pywrap_cpu_feature_guard` is a shared object library `_pywrap_cpu_feature_guard.so` which exists, but seems it have an issue with succesfull load on Android platform.

I have no clue how to workaround it. Some users were able to run `tensorflow-lite` with Kivy on Android, but not `tensorflow`:

[Building Kivy Android app with Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967553/building-kivy-android-app-with-tensorflow)

https://github.com/Android-for-Python/c4k_tflite_example

https://medium.com/@vvalouch/from-keras-to-android-with-tensorflow-lite-7581368aa23e

Answer (score 0):

requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd==0.104.1,nltk,numpy,keras

That's all you need to add to the buildozer requirements line for getting an error free app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it going, following [kivy buildozer](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html?highlight=android)
I guess my mistake was not to follow

> Install buildozer’s dependencies.

I suspect the cython version given there was essential.